# Python / Discord: "Unclosed Connector connections"

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, connector

the below script connects to discord, and then disconnects again.
that works perfectly and prints out these two items:

> **** Logged in!

> **** End

But when the script ends, I get this additional warning:

> Unclosed connector

> connections:
> ['[(<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x7f18f84e6080>,
> 3702249.404694462)]']

> connector: <aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector object at 0x7f18f70af4c0>

I tried many ways but have not figured out how to et around this; any pointers are welcome. Of course I could simply ignore it, but I'd prefer to handle this "graciously".

**Update:**
Since my question has been downvoted as "not enough research" done, sharing how I have approached it so far. I by purpose did not include all the below attempts, because they all failed; the code I pasted is a minimum working example out of a larger code that allows reproducing the problem easily.

I did try:

- to define a session (aiohttp.ClientSession()) and then awaiting to close it
- leverage the @client.event "on_disconnect()" to close the session
- use "bot.run" rather than "client.run"; and even put that into a async run
- add a sleep delay to see whether then the connection would be closed before the script ends
- figure it out by looking at the discord examples ([link](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/tree/master/examples))
- study the similar stackoverflow posts and see whether I could get them to work for my case, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65343804/unclosed-connector-error-connector-aiohttp-connector-tcpconnector-object-at-0), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76773087/aiohttp-with-connector-session-is-closed-unclosed-connector-excepions) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57175393/closing-clientsession-when-keyboard-interrupt)

Thus any pointers that guide me on the right path are highly appreciated. If people still feel my question is "unprepared", appreciate a comment as to how I could make it better...

```
import discord
import asyncio

# Suppress login messages from discord
import logging
logging.getLogger("discord.client").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
logging.getLogger("discord.gateway").setLevel(logging.WARNING)

intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('**** Logged in!')
    await client.close()

# Starts the script:
DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN = 'xxx'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    client.run(DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN)
    print('**** End')
```